# rpc.mountd segfaults when trying to mount an nfs share

Tags: linux, debian, nfs, network-attached-storage, segmentation-fault

I have a pair of **QNAP TS859U-RP nas devices** running Linux version 2.6.33.2. These boxes are based on Debian. They are experiencing the same failure.

When I try to mount an nfs share as root as following:

```sh
mount nasb:/content /mnt/nasb/blah/
```

It gives a timeout on the client:

```sh
mount: mount to NFS server 'nasb' failed: timed out (retrying).  
mount: mount to NFS server 'nasb' failed: timed out (retrying).
```

There is also an error written to logs/kmsg on the nas like:

```sh
<6>rpc.mountd[522]: segfault at b73aa078 ip b76fdf56 sp bf8b03a4 error 7 in libuLinux_statistics.so.0.0[b76fd000+3000]  
<6>rpc.mountd[6539]: segfault at b7418078 ip b776bf56 sp bfd69a94 error 7 in libuLinux_statistics.so.0.0[b776b000+3000]  
... repeating
```

`rpc.mountd` is restarted, and the device momentarily stops serving nfs requests to all hosts. This device has that very same nfs share mounted on 23 other hosts and functioning as confirmed by running `netstat -a | grep nfs | grep ESTAB | wc -l` on the nas. I know there is some soft limit to the number of hosts that can mount a particular nfs share but either way it shouldn't segfault but return some error.

This is a software raid6 volume formatted with ext4. I tried contacting support a few times but have gotten nothing but the standard upgrade/reapply your firmware and reboot response. No satisfaction :( Any ideas on tracking down the error with `rpc.mountd/libuLinux_statistics.so` would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I'd start with strace-ing rpc.mountd, and see which syscall it's failing on.  Alternately, if you can afford the downtime for the other clients, you might try attaching a debugger, "gdb -p <pid of rpc.mountd> then hit "c" for continue.  Then trigger the error - you might see the segfault happen (which will then cause the debugger to stop the process), then you can run bt to see a backtrace.

Comment: Those are excellent suggestions. I will see about getting some debugging tools installed using ipkg on this nas.

Comment: Thx again for the suggestions @malcolmpdx. I pasted the output of strace [here](http://pastebin.com/GKvVV1tQ). I don't see anything obvious right before the segfault but that could be due to my lack of interpretation skills. Much respect to anyone that can take a look at that and give some insight.

Comment: @brandon - the call before the segfault is a shared memory function.  What's your memory usage on the server look like?  It's possible that's why many clients work, and then these two don't - lack of memory available.  Easy test would be to turn off a few of the other clients, and then see if these two can connect.

Comment: These devices each have 1 GB of ram installed without about 20% of that being free. I can certainly try your suggestion during some off peak hour to add credit or remove validity to that theory. Good thinking.

Comment: @brandon - upon further consideration, that shared memory call actually returned with a good value...likely a red herring.  So, really, I'd get GDB involved here.

Comment: Thank you: @malcolmpdx. I think I have it narrowed down to something going south during the firmware upgrade which didn't update a file.. /usr/lib/libuLinux_statistics.so. I reapplied the firmware update, the file was updated, and the problem has yet to manifest itself again. I couldn't have done it (at least not in a reasonable time) without your suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you: @malcolmpdx. I think I have it narrowed down to something going south during the firmware upgrade which didn't update a file.. /usr/lib/libuLinux_statistics.so. I reapplied the firmware update, the file was updated, and the problem has yet to manifest itself again. I couldn't have done it (at least not in a reasonable time) without your suggestions.

Comment: Great to hear it!  Congrats on figuring it out.